# Why is IN operator showing wrong results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this table `BarCode`, when I do a in query like this

```
SELECT Barcode 
FROM BarcodeTable 
WHERE BarCode IN 
            (
                '53-3-1',
                '51-1-1',
                '51-2-1',
                '50-10-1',
                '50-8-1',
                '51-4-1',
                '50-1-1'
            )
```

why do I get

```
53-3-1
50-1-1
50-8-1
50-10-1
51-1-1
51-2-1
51-4-1
```

Instead of ????

```
53-3-1
51-1-1
51-2-1
50-10-1
50-8-1
51-4-1
50-1-1
```

Why does SQL changing the order of barcodes? Because of the way SQL is ordering them (by itself) is causing an error in a dynamic query that is being executed by `sp_executesql` that relies on the order I send the input. Why is the SQL changing input order by itself?

*51-4-1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` does not imply any ordering of the final result:

This SQL:

```
... WHERE x IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Should produce the same results as this:

```
... WHERE x IN (3, 2, 1)
```

The `IN` clause only filters the rows, basically, for each row you can think of it as just asking "should this row be part of the resultset?".

To get a specific ordering, you're going to have to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your statement.

To get a specific order, you can use an inline table:

```
SELECT Barcode
FROM BarcodeTable
    inner join (values
        ('*53-3-1*',  1),
        ('*51-1-1*',  2),
        ('*51-2-1*',  3),
        ('*50-10-1*', 4),
        ('*50-8-1*',  5),
        ('*51-4-1*',  6),
        ('*50-1-1*',  7)) as DummyTable (value, sortorder)
    on BarCode = value
order by
    sortorder
```

This will order by the sortorder field of the DummyTable.

You can not trick SQL Server into using the `IN` clause itself for ordering, you *have* to add an `ORDER BY` in some form or another.

You can also use a `CASE WHEN ...` expression to produce the sort order value depending on the barcode:

```
SELECT Barcode
FROM BarcodeTable
WHERE BarCode IN ('*53-3-1*', '*51-1-1*', '*51-2-1*', '*50-10-1*', '*50-8-1*', '*51-4-1*', '*50-1-1*')
ORDER BY
    CASE BarCode
        WHEN '*53-3-1*'  THEN 1
        WHEN '*51-1-1*'  THEN 2
        WHEN '*51-2-1*'  THEN 3
        WHEN '*50-10-1*' THEN 4
        WHEN '*50-8-1*'  THEN 5
        WHEN '*51-4-1*'  THEN 6
        WHEN '*50-1-1*'  THEN 7
    END
```

As the comment by Lieven suggests, there's an alternative on SQL Server 2005, using the `WITH` clause:

```
WITH DummyTable (value, sortorder) AS (
    SELECT '*53-3-1*' AS value,  1 AS sortorder
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '*51-1-1*',  2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '*51-2-1*',  3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '*50-10-1*', 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '*50-8-1*',  5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '*51-4-1*',  6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '*50-1-1*',  7
)
SELECT Barcode
FROM BarcodeTable
    inner join DummyTable
    on BarCode = value
order by
    sortorder
```

(note, I'm no expert in the usage of `WITH`, the above was just something I hacked together, but seems to work)

Comment: Is there a way, I can output the data in the order I specified the input for `IN`? Because the query that is executing is dynamic sql, and it depends on the order it was specified in. I know I can use cursor, but I don't wanna do that.

Comment: Note, I'm not sure the `VALUES` syntax works in SQL Server 2005. I only tested this on 2008.

Comment: +1. 2005 doesn't have a value constructor but you can get the same effect using a `with` statement.

Comment: @Razort4x - What part of the statement is dynamic? The IN statement or the entire select?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you specify an order by statement, you should not rely on particular order in the output. You must provide an `ORDER BY` to get what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

To make your query order as you're expecting, you need to add an `ORDER BY`, or the ordering will be unreliable. Something like this should work but depending on your volume of barcodes it may in the end be easier to order it correctly in code once the result is returned;

```
SELECT Barcode 
FROM BarcodeTable 
WHERE BarCode IN ('*53-3-1*','*51-1-1*','*51-2-1*','*50-10-1*',
                  '*50-8-1*','*51-4-1*','*50-1-1*')
ORDER BY CASE BarCode WHEN '*53-3-1*'  THEN 1
                      WHEN '*51-1-1*'  THEN 2
                      WHEN '*51-2-1*'  THEN 3
                      WHEN '*50-10-1*' THEN 4
                      WHEN '*50-8-1*'  THEN 5
                      WHEN '*51-4-1*'  THEN 6
                      WHEN '*50-1-1*'  THEN 7
                      END
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code**

```
SELECT Barcode ,CASE Col_Order WHEN '53-3-1'  THEN 1
                      WHEN '51-1-1'  THEN 2
                      WHEN '51-2-1'  THEN 3
                      WHEN '50-10-1' THEN 4
                      WHEN '50-8-1'  THEN 5
                      WHEN '51-4-1'  THEN 6
                      WHEN '50-1-1'  THEN 7 
                      END     
FROM BarcodeTable 
WHERE BarCode IN 
            (
                '53-3-1',
                '51-1-1',
                '51-2-1',
                '50-10-1',
                '50-8-1',
                '51-4-1',
                '50-1-1'
            )    
ORDER BY Col_Order
```